# update html with javascript on an interval with directory size in php

Tags: php, javascript, intervals

I'm trying to get the size of a directory calculated every 3 seconds.
The calculation succeeds and the size gets displayed but it does not update. 
This is the code at the moment:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = sizeRefresh;
    function updatesize() {  
        $dir_size = <?php 
                        $dir = "pics"; 
                        function dirSize($directory) { 
                        $size = 0; 
                        foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)) as $file){ 
                        $size+=$file->getSize(); 
                        } 
                        echo json_encode(round($size/1024,0) . " KB<br>" . round($size/1024/1024,0) . "MB<br>" . round($size/1024/1024/1024,0) . "GB" ); 
                        } 
                        dirSize($dir) 
                        ?>;

        var hsize = document.getElementById('sizemark');
        hsize.innerHTML = $dir_size
        }


    function sizeRefresh() {
        setInterval("updatesize()", 3000);
    }
</script>
<h1 id='sizemark' > size </h1>
```

What am i doing wrong?

thank you.

Comment: Anyway it's was not a good idea to mess server side code (PHP) with the client side code (JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply because php part of the code work only once. You should instead make new request to your server every 3 (30-60 is better) seconds - reload a page (not a good idea) or use ajax.

Comment: thank you @Aleko. How do i make a new request in a setup like this? should i have the php code in its own file and send a request to that every 30-60 seconds? or is there an easier way without having to work with a separate file?

Comment: Ok it's allright now, I solved it using ajax, like you, @Aleko, suggested. Thank you.